# How can I "buffered" mine Oracle logs using LogMiner with 'committed data only' option properly?

Tags: oracle, log

Using Oracle LogMiner with committed data only flag,
According to the Oracle documentation, all the committed records with the same `commit scn`, will be joined together and will appear in a sequence.

I want to scan the log, but not all in a one session, because it will take long time to load, so I'm getting some number (say 1000) and read this amount each time with committed only flag.

**My questions is:** when I give a sequence between `start scn` to `end scn` like this:

```
DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR (
startScn=>start_value, 
endScn=>end_value,
options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+COMMITTED_DATA_ONLY+CONTINUOUS_MINE+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROWID_IN_STMT
);
```

Lets say I have a transaction which committed in the given range, but started in some scn before the range, does it still should give all the committed rows together, including the starting scn, or just all the committed rows with the same commit scn, that are in the given range?

If the 2nd is correct, Do I get the pre-range committed records at all? since it still uncommitted in the previous range, and now it is committed, so when I have a long transactions it look like a flaw in the mechanism.

Thanks for any thought